# Title of shakersort

Tags: java, sorting

I am currently taking a Data Structure and Algorithm and part of an exercise is to
implement the shaker sort algorithm. Instead of separating two for loops, I have included a
for-j loop inside a for-i loop. Is that possible?

```
public static void shakerSort(int array[], int n) 
{
    boolean swapped = true;
    while (swapped) 
    {
         swapped = false;
         for (int i = 0; i < n - 1; i++) 
         {
             if (array[i] > array[i + 1]) 
             {
                    int temp = array[i];
                    array[i] = array[i + 1];
                    array[i + 1] = temp;
                    swapped = true;
             }
                
             if (i == n - 2) 
             {
                 if (!swappped)
                 {
                    break;
                 }
                 else
                 {
                     swapped = false;
                     for (int j = n - 1; j > 0; j--) 
                     {
                          if (array[j - 1] > array[j]) 
                          {
                               int temp = array[j];
                               array[j] = array[j - 1];
                               array[j - 1] = temp;
                               swapped = true;
                          }
                     }
                     if (!swapped) 
                     {
                       break;
                     }
                 }     
             }
        }
    }
```

Output:

```
   -5
   -3
    5 
    9 
   11 
   12
   15
   18
```

Comment: `[2, 3, 1]` won't get sorted successfully because of the first `if !swapped break`.

Comment: @sp00m thank you very much., I changed the code as you said . Can you check my code?